# DRY up simple conditionals with some shared action

Tags: javascript

I need to test two conditions. Either could be true (but not both). If neither are true, we do nothing. If either are true, we perform a common action. If the second condition is true, we perform an additional action. Seems simple enough, but as I try to write the code, I find myself repeating either the condition or the action, and it doesn't feel as DRY as it might be.

To illustrate with pseudocode…

We repeat one of the conditions:

```
if a | b {
    do  x
    if b {
        do y
    }
}
```

Or, we repeat one of the actions:

```
if a {
    do x
} else if b {
    do x
    do y
}
```

I might not stop to worry about this normally, except that both conditionals and actions are one-liners that process regular expressions—complex enough to not want to repeat them, but too short to warrant their own functions.

I could throw a boolean variable into the mix …

```
var doX = false
if a {
    doX = true
} else if b {
    doX = true
    do y
}
if doX {
    do x
}
```

… but that feels a bit kludgy.

Is there a DRYer way of doing this—some beautiful, concise conditional logic that I haven't thought of? (I'm working in JavaScript at the moment, but I'm happy for a better example in any language.)

**Update:** In the end, I went with my third (admittedly 'kludgy') option. Sergio's suggestion of capturing each match first certainly looks the nicest and avoids code repetition, but then you lose the performance benefit of short-circuit evaluation (i.e. there's no need to evaluate b if a is already known to be true.) Since, in my particular app, this block of code is run many, many times on a potentially huge list of strings, that made more sense. (The order of x and y didn't matter.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> if a | b {
>   do  x
>   if b {
>     do y
>   }
> }
> ```

This is so nice and readable, you probably can't beat that.

> both conditionals and actions are one-liners that process regular expressions

Ah, that's where the question stems from. Indeed, if instead of `a` and `b` there are long-ish and impenetrable regexes, I can see how this can make it less clear. What if you extract the conditions?

```
var a = /regex 1 check/
var b = /regex 2 check/

if a | b {
    do  x
    if b {
        do y
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio. You know, I probably just needed someone to tell me I wasn't crazy and that my conditional logic was actually fine. (The curse of working alone.) Yes, testing each regex match first and reusing those booleans makes a lot of sense. :-)

Comment: @Kal "The curse of working alone." - yeah, check out some of my early questions :)

Comment: If only my questions were getting better over time! I'll blame today's on the roaring head cold. ;-)

Comment: In the end, I went back to my third (admittedly 'kludgy') option. Sergio's suggestion of capturing each match first certainly looks the nicest and avoids code repetition, but then you lose the performance benefit of short-circuit evaluation (i.e. there's no need to evaluate `b` if `a` is already known to be true.) A small thing perhaps, but this block of code is run many, many times on a potentially huge list of strings, so it's worth it I think.

Comment: @Kal: yes, performance and readability are often at odds with each other :/

Comment: @Kal: ah, but in your kludgy approach `y` happens before `x`. While it may not matter for your case, it's still not the same thing as the original snippet.

Comment: Ah yes you're right. In my case the order of x and y didn't matter. If it did, I suppose I could delay y with yet another variable and kludge it up some more. :-/ As much as I tried to generalise the question (to make it infinitely applicable), I guess it just demonstrates the principle of choosing the right tool for the actual task at hand hey.